# Laplacian with singular potential

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $S$ be a $2$-dimensional sphere. Let $p$ be a point in $S$. Let $L$ be a second order elliptic partial differential operator with smooth coefficients defined over the complement of $p$. Near $p$, $S$ is parametrised conformally by the Poincaré Disk, $\Bbb{D}^*$. We suppose that, with respect to this parametrisation, $L$ has the form

$$
L = \Delta + \alpha r^{-2} + \beta \log(r)^2 r^{-2},
$$

where $\Delta$ is the standard Laplacian and $r=\|x\|$.

Can someone please tell me which function spaces I should use over $S$ to make $L$ into a Fredholm  operator, and what the Fredholm Index of the resulting operator would be?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, r =|x|. Is not |x| =1 on the standard sphere??  Perhaps you mean $r(x) = dist_{S^2}(p, x)$?  Where did this problem originate?

Comment: I mean that I'm working in a conformal chart about $p$ which is biholomorphic to the Poincaré disk. The above formula is the expression for $L$ inside this chart. Alternatively, since I'm really only interested in understanding the behaviour of the operator near the singularity, you can think of the operator as acting on spaces of functions defined over the disk $\Bbb{D}$ and which vanish over the boundary.

Comment: The operator in question arises as the Jacobi operator of the Grimm Paraboloid, which is a complete, radially symmetric surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ whose evolution under the mean curvature flow coincides with vertical translations.

Comment: Indeed, you can use $r(x)=d(p,x)$, if you like...

Answer (score 1):

When $\alpha=0$ and $\beta<0$, which is the case which really interests me, it turns out to actually be a fairly straightforward application of the theory of unbounded operators. First, to simplify things, we suppose that $\beta=-1$, and we compose with the conformal mapping $\Phi:S^1\times[0,\infty[\rightarrow\Bbb{D}^*$ given by $\Phi(\theta,t)=e^{i\theta-t}$. This leads to the operator

$$
L:= \Delta - t^2 = \partial_\theta^2 + \partial_t^2 - t^2.
$$

We define the graph of $L$, $G(L)$ to be the set of all pairs $(f,g)\in L^2\times L^2$ such that $Lf=g$ in the weak sense. Since this is a closed condition, the graph of $L$ is a closed subspace of $L^2\times L^2$ and is therefore a Hilbert space in its own right. Furthermore, the projection onto the first component is injective, and we define the domain of $L$, $D(L)$ to be the image of this projection. We furnish the domain of $L$ with the unique norm that makes this projection into an isometry. That is, for all $f\in D(L)$

$$
\|f\|_{D(L)}^2 = \|f\|_{L^2}^2 + \|Lf\|_{L^2}^2.
$$

Using the negativity of the potiential, we show that the canonical embeding of $D(L)$ into $L^2$ is a compact mapping. From this, we deduce that $L$ has finite dimensional kernel (actually, trivial kernel), and closed image. We then show that the image of $L$ contains every smooth function of compact support. It follows from closure of the image that $L$ is surjective. In summary, $L$ defines a linear isomorphism from $D(L)$ into $L^2$. [1] and [2] are good references for these standard techniques.

Finally, with a little bit more work, we show that the norm $\|\cdot\|_{D(L)}$ is equivalent to the following weighted Sobolev Norm:

$$
\|f\|_{H^2_w}^2 = \int t^2 f^2 + \int t \|Df\|^2 + \int \left|\Delta f\right|^2.
$$

$\|\cdot\|_{H^2_w}$ is therefore the desired norm.

[1] Gilbarg D., Trudinger N.S., Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order.

[2] Lax P.D., Functional Analysis.

Bernard Helffer's courses on Spectral Theory are probably also helpful.

http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~helffer/